# Strange behavior with xss clean

Tags: codeigniter, url, codeigniter-2, xss

In the following lines:

```
var_dump($this->uri->segment(3));
$get = $this->security->xss_clean($this->uri->segment(3));
var_dump($get);
```

How could the first `var_dump` print

```
string(34) "debut=0&combien=30&s=1&telephone=4"
```

and the second (after the `xss_clean`)

```
string(29) "debut 0&combien=30&s=1&teleph"
```

I'm a bit confused here.

EDIT:

I've been debugging this, and it's the `_remove_evil_attributes()` function in `security` class that make the transformation for this and only this string

The line 641 in the security class:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<?)(\/?[^><]+?)([^A-Za-z<>\-])(.*?)('.implode('|', $attribs).')(.*?)([\s><]?)([><]*)/i', '$1$2 $4$6$7$8', $str, -1, $count);
```

conciders `"one\\=4"` (as in telephone=4") to be an evil attribute. Ok, now it's bigger than me...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is normal nowdays since codeigniter is not supported any more (at least temporally) because they are [seeking new owner for](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/ellislab-seeking-new-owner-for-codeigniter).

So, my recommendation is override the `Security` class at `core/` directory.

Comment: That's what I noticed, they put words in the evil array word like "alert" ... I don't think a decent hacker would use the alert to hijack your cookies..